# A basic question about algebraic groups on inversion being a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G = GL_n(k)$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. I know that the inversion $i$ is a morphism but I was wondering how I can show this.

By definition I have to show that 
1) $i: G \rightarrow G$ is continuous 
2) for all open $V \subseteq G$ for all $f \in O_G(V)$, we have 
$f \circ i \in O_G(i^{-1} (V) )$.

I know that $GL_n(k)$ is an algebraic group so $i$ is a morphism but I am struggling to provide the details for it. Details would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $GL_2 {}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using cofactor matrices, you can determine an expression of $i(A)$ as a rational function of the coefficient of $A$.

[Continuity of rational functions between affine algebraic sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709984/continuity-of-rational-functions-between-affine-algebraic-sets)